# copy column names into the "label" attribute

Tags: r, tidyr

I would like to the copy column names (for some columns) into the "label" attribute. The code below works, but requires me to type every line and type out the column name for every column I'd like:

```
data(mtcars)

attr(mtcars$mpg, "label") <- "mpg"
attr(mtcars$cyl, "label") <- "cyl"
attr(mtcars$qsec, "label") <- "qsec"
```

Is there anyway to take a vector of columns I'd like to label, and then copy the column names into the label attribute? I imagine I'd start with something like this:

```
data(mtcars)

vectorofcolumnstolabel <- c("mpg","cyl","qsec")
```

Thank you.

**An alternative question that might solve the same problem in a different way**:

With Tidy data, if you have very long column names, eg. "Wage of Full Time White Males Aged 30-39", and you want to rename to say "white30s": where would you normally store the full description of the column? Is the "label" attribute the best place for this?

Thank you.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like a data dictionary, why not store it outside your data? Carrying it with the data frame seems like adding an unnecessary complication to me. If you need the long description for tables, *etc.* then store it in a separate *df* as a key-value pair with the column name as the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
  mtcars[]=Map(`attr<-`,mtcars,"labels",names(mtcars))
```

Comment: Why are you putting square brackets on the data frame? Any it is better practice to use `colnames` when you want to return the column names of a data frame

Comment: well that was just to store the results back to the dataframe.. But you do nt need to. At the same time a data frame is just but a list arranged. so using names is perfectly fine. colnames is particularly for matrices, arrays...

Comment: I did not downvote, and I do not understand why there are downvotes.

I tried:
`Map(`attr<-`,mtcars,"label",names(mtcars))`
but it didn't give me the labels on the columns (which are visible in R Studio under the column headings using the code I provided above)

Comment: you need to call the columns. eg `mtcars$disp`

Comment: sorry I did edit it. I had removed the first edition. Now try it again

Comment: Still don't understand the downvote, the code works perfectly. Is there an easy way to only do it for some columns?
`vectorofcolumnstolabel <- c("mpg","cyl","qsec")`

Comment: Yes, just do `mtcars[vectorofcolumnstolabel]=Map(`attr<-`,mtcars[vectorofcolumnstolabel],"labels",names(mtcars))`